# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using UITextField.text in other UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

i have two view controllers, one with `UITableView` for displaying data - and one for adding data. the `UITableView` controller have some demo rows. the demo rows are displayed from class that holds all data for `UITableView` controller. with this class we can add rows from all controllers. when i adding row from add data controller **without using `UITextField.text`**, and returning to `UITableView` controller, the row adds and all working perfectly. when i adding data from `UITextField.text`, the `UITableView` controller crashed with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

**some code:**

**class that holds all data's add method:**

```
- (BCItem *)createCafeWithCafeName:(NSString *)name
                     cafeChain:(NSString *)chain
                    cafeStreet:(NSString *)street
                      cafeCity:(NSString *)city
                      cafeInfo:(NSString *)info
                       cafeLog:(NSString *)log
                       cafeLig:(NSString *)lig
{
    BCItem *p = [[BCItem alloc] initWithCafeName:name cafeChain:chain cafeStreet:street cafeCity:city cafeInfo:info cafeLog:log cafeLig:lig];

    [allCafesMutable addObject:p];

    return p;
}
```

**add method:**

```
[[BCItemStore sharedStore] createCafeWithCafeName:name.text cafeChain:chain.text cafeStreet:street.text cafeCity:city.text cafeInfo:info.text cafeLog:log.text cafeLig:lig.text];
```

all the `UITextField` are released.
what is the problem?

**EDIT:**

the app crashed when i trying to get data from the class where the data stored.

Comment: when getting the data from the `BCItem`

Comment: (from the class that holds the data for the `UITableView` controller)

Comment: Please show us how you initialized the 'UITextField' and the complete error message. Thanks

Comment: in normally way, with the xib

Comment: Maybe this `UITextField` isn't connect correctly. Look at your ViewController Object in xib if in `Connections Inspector` is all ok.

Comment: thanks, i reconnect the fields and all worked.

Answer (score 0):

As `@TomaszSzulc3` specified in his comment the issue was that the UITextField wasnted connected correctly. As such, the solution involved reconnecting the fields.